# Regex to insert a space between uppercase and lowercase letters

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have text like

```
CacciaMagazineOttobre2020
RumoreFebbraio2021
```

To add a space between letters and numbers in this way

```
CacciaMagazineOttobre 2020
RumoreFebbraio 2021
```

I use this regex

Find: `([a-z])([0-9])`
Replace:  `\1 \2`

I try to understand how insert a space between uppercase and lowercase letters to have this final output

```
Caccia Magazine Ottobre 2020
Rumore Febbraio 2021
```

I try a regex like

Find: `([a-z])([A-Z])`
Replace: `\1 \2`

but doesn't work.

Comment: For me it works; didn't you forget to check the _Match case_ box?

Comment: Yes, I realized I forgot to check the box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z0-9])`
- Replace with: `A SINGLE SPACE`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=[a-z])   # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a small letter before current position
(?=[A-Z0-9])  # positive lookahead, make sure we have an uppercase or a digit after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you, your solution is good. I test also Find: `(.)([A-Z])` replace: `\1 \2` but is limited

Comment: @AlexDoc: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: Is there a solution if I want insert this kind of space in renaming files context? I post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66928979/rename-files-by-inserting-a-space-before-capital-letters

Comment: @AlexDoc: Well, I don't know what regex flavor is used in batch. You may try find: `([a-z])([A-Z])` and replace with `$1 $2` or `\1 \2`